# Trying to use the Google "Load a Scaled Down Version into Memory" method but no images are displaying

Tags: image, android-studio, android-imageview, android-bitmap, android-memory

I'm making a basic puzzle app game and I'm trying to display the levels so the player can choose one of them.

The pictures are all around 1000x1000 pixels and I'm setting them to imageviews that around shrunk to 1/3 of the screen width squared. There are about 40 levels so that means there are 40 images to be displayed. This is my first time using android studio so I didn't expect the app to start lagging when I loaded 6 images onto the screen.

My app stopped running because it was running out of memory, so I looked online to find a way to reduce the image quality. I came upon google's answer [Where they load the image into a bitmap, then load it again with the dimensions changed.](https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/graphics/load-bitmap.html#load-bitmap) Since I'm such a beginner I'm not able to fully understand what the methods are doing so I just copy and pasted it into my code.

I set everything up like the tutorial told me to but when I ran my app, the images stopped displaying at all.

My code:

```
public class MainMenuPuzzle {
//all puzzle images are equally sized squares so this int stores the sidelengths
private int width = Constants.SCREEN_WIDTH/3;
private ImageView image;
//stores the id of the image using R.id.filename
int id;
//changes the margins of the imageview
public ViewGroup.LayoutParams params;
//variables for margins on each side
private int l;
private int t;
private int r = 0;
private int b = 0;



public MainMenuPuzzle(ImageView image, Activity activity,int row, int column,int id){

    this.image = image;
    this.id = id;

    ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = image.getLayoutParams();
    final RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) image.getLayoutParams();

    //there are 3 images displayed in every row, adjusts the margin depending on which column the image is in
    if (column == 1){
        l = 0;
    }
    else if(column == 2){
        l = width;
    }
    else{
        l = width*2;
    }
    //the vertical margin is based on which row of images the image is in
    t = ((row-1)*width)+Constants.SCREEN_HEIGHT;

    lp.width =width;
    lp.height= width;
    lp.setMargins(l,t,r,b);

    //where I attempt to reduce the quality of the image so my app doesn't lag lmao
    image.setImageBitmap(
            decodeSampledBitmapFromResource(Constants.CURRENT_CONTEXT.getResources(), id, width, width));

    image.setLayoutParams(params);

}
//from google
public static int calculateInSampleSize(
        BitmapFactory.Options options, int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {
    // Raw height and width of image
    final int height = options.outHeight;
    final int width = options.outWidth;
    int inSampleSize = 1;

    if (height > reqHeight || width > reqWidth) {

        final int halfHeight = height / 2;
        final int halfWidth = width / 2;

        // Calculate the largest inSampleSize value that is a power of 2 and keeps both
        // height and width larger than the requested height and width.
        while ((halfHeight / inSampleSize) > reqHeight
                && (halfWidth / inSampleSize) > reqWidth) {
            inSampleSize *= 2;
        }
    }

    return inSampleSize;
}
//from google
public static Bitmap decodeSampledBitmapFromResource(Resources res, int resId,
                                                     int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {

    // First decode with inJustDecodeBounds=true to check dimensions
    final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
    BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, resId, options);

    // Calculate inSampleSize
    options.inSampleSize = calculateInSampleSize(options, reqWidth, reqHeight);

    // Decode bitmap with inSampleSize set
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
    return BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, resId, options);
}

//random methods because I'm too lazy to make getters and setters for everything
public ImageView getImage(){
    return image;
}

public void setHeight(int height){
    params.height = height;
}

public void setWidth(int width){
    params.width = width;
}
}
```